# Migrate AngularJS 1.4.7 to 1.6

Tags: angularjs

We have a fairly large enterprise application based on AngularJS 1.4.7. I have been asked to assess an effort to migrate the app into a version 1.6... because the current (1.4.7) version has multiple security vulnerabilities that were addressed in the version 1.6.7. I have been researching for migration tools or other resources and did not find much. I found this:

[Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-4-to-1-5)

that explains what was added/changed, but doesn't provide any guidelines of what kind of code changes should take a place. If someone has a personal experience of doing a similar migration please share. I know I am shooting in the dark but that is where I am in now.

Comment: You pretty much just need to update and see what breaks aside from searching for the specified changes in your source. This is why it is important to write good tests, they are great at pointing out what doesn't work after an upgrade.

Comment: But what I read is that I have to change my directives to be components - template plus controller. Is that a true statement?

Comment: No, they suggest you convert ng-controller directive usages into components, but this is not a requirement. Components are basically directives with "best practice" presets like controllerAs defaults to vm, controllers are defaulted to an empty function etc...

Comment: Alright, that is great news. Thanks.